# Whats going on in this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm reading through a shell script and i came across this:

```
rpm -q ${package} >&2 && {
log notice "Package ${package} is already installed. Great."
return 0 }
```

This has been working for a long time apparently but i cant figure out what kind of syntax this this.. the part inside the curly braces..how can you have curly braces like that, ive never seen bash shell scripting like that before where you suddently use curly braces without any function name or anything and that the rpm -q just implicitly is an if statement.

I understand what it does, its fairly obvious since bash is pretty easy but its the syntax that throws me.

This is the code for the function:

```
434 yum_install() {
435   [[ $# -lt 1 ]] && die "not enough parameters"
436   local package="${1}"
437
438   log info "Verifying package ${package} with rpm"
439   if test -z "${package}"; then
440     die "no package name provided to yum_install"
441   fi
442
443   # Return if package is already installed
444   rpm -q ${package} >&2 && {
445     log notice "Package ${package} is already installed. Great."
446     return 0
447   }
448
449   die "Package ${package} required. Please install."
450 }
```

Comment: It's a code block. It's not that strange, you can use it even in C...

Comment: `since bash is pretty easy but its the syntax that throws me` Haha!

Comment: It's a fallacy to believe that shell programming is easy, you better don't fall for it.

Comment: Is there any reason for wanting to use this kind of syntax in a shell script? (subshells and grouping of commands), in the manual it says that it uses more system resources, it doesnt say anything about advantages...it says this "let the script do parallel processing, in effect executing multiple subtasks simultaneously" and then in the code example it says that the while loop will run forever, so the main script and the subshell doesnt really run in paralell

Comment: @user2959896 You're referring to the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide? I'm not impressed by its wording there. There is no parallel processing unless the subshell is executed in the background. Most of the time, a bare command list in curlies is sufficient. If you get more proficient with shell, you will find cases where a subshell serves you better.

Comment: In fact, the braces are not part of the function declaration syntax. A shell function simply needs a compound command following `funcname ()`, and the `{...}` is just one possibility. `funcname () ( ...)` is legal, as is `funcname () while something; do ... done`, etc.

Comment: It's easy to write something that runs in shell; it's another matter to write something that runs the way you intended :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code between `{}` is a *code block*. It will get executed only if the `rpm` command succeeds. That's because both commands are concatenated with the AND operator `&&`

While a code block between `()` launches a subshell, a code block between curly brackets does not launch a subshell. You can follow [this guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)

However, in the form you've posted the command it will lead to a syntax error:

```
can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

**Update** You told in comments that the snippet is part of a function. If part of a function the `return 0` is ok.

Comment: It works and has been working for a long time, the code is inside a function and is also using the external log function with a parameter so i dont think it will work for you unless you create these, there is a lot of utility functions sourced in from other directories..the package is also one of the parameters to the function the code is placed in

Comment: i know it isnt working for you, i added the { on the same line as text, it needs a ; or a newline to work according to documenation linked to be devnull

Comment: As an aside, there's actually at least one shell (busybox `ash` implementation) where `return` works fine when called at the top level: it just behaves like `exit` in that case. I think it's even possible to build busybox so that invoking it as `bash` just calls its `ash` implementation, and I have vague memories of running into that in the wild. (I think they do it to be compatible with all the scripts which are written by people who hashbang their scripts to bash chronically, even for scripts which are broadly /bin/sh compatible).

Comment: @mtraceur same for dash... Thanks for the follow up!